# Finding path of required module

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to print out the path of the module loaded with `require()`.

I was browsing through the React repository and looking at the test files. 
Almost every file has `React = require('React')` however the module is not [present](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/package.json) in the `node_modules` folder (obviously). I was curious as to where it was being loaded from as there is no relative path inside the require function. Even deeply nested test files use `require('React')`, how is it being resolved if it isn't in the `node_modules` folder?

I've tried things like `require.resolve('React')` in the node console but keep getting `Error: Cannot find module 'React'`. Strangely even `require('React')` inside the console yields the same result.